# UILongPressGestureRecognizer only checks for numberOfTouchesRequired at initial touch

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have an app that has three long press gestures for 1,2, and 3 touches.

An Issue: through testing, my success rate of getting 2 or 3 touches to register correctly at the start of gesture recognition was far less than 100%. In further testing, it appears that the UILongPressGestureRecognizer [LPGR] only checks for the number of touches at the start and fails instantly if the number of touches is not what it's expecting.

My (potential) solution: I have started building a generic UIGestureRecognizer that will check for the number of touches at the end of a time interval, then pass touches to whatever branch of code that handles what was 1,2,and 3 touches.

My Question: Is there a better way? And barring that, is there a way to use the code already in an existing gestureRecognizers? I have not been able to actually change the state through reference (someRecognizer.state = .changed does not seem to do anything)

Comment: Have you changed the `.minimumPressDuration`? It defaults to `0.5`, and I don't have a problem with detecting 1, 2 or 3 touches, even when deliberately delaying between the first, second and third fingers.

Comment: I found the issue - a pinch gesture was interfering when the touches = 2. So initial touches could be 1 2 or 3, but if it was counted as 2 nothing else would fire.